# Search and scroll to word on page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, search, scroll

My client wants to add a search box on specific pages that will allow their user to search for a product and it will scroll to that text. This way it's easier for her to direct her clients to the right part of the page.

This is easily done using Ctrl-F with the browsers search function. Unfortunately the client wants the search to be part of the site.

Any advice on how to accomplish this? I've struggled to find a wordpress plug-in and any JQuery code I've used around the internet has failed me.

Thanks kindly in advance!

Comment: I think this question already has been asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: This person wants it to scroll to a certain word on the page, not an element.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about its browser support, but you can call `window.find("your query here")` to use the browser's Ctrl+F functionality

[*More info here*](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/find_dia.htm)

Comment: Yeah! That is a most simple way (and with a highlight text) using the browser automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`:contains` selector.](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("window").scrollTop($("*:contains('search text here'):eq(n)").offset().top);
```

where `n` is the nth-match. You can probably get the number of matches first then by pressing enter or tab then scroll to the `++n`-th match.

Comment: How would I make this JQuery bit wordpress ready? I'd like to give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: You need to add a text field and a function which is called when the value of text field is changed.

    `$("input#search").change(function(){
        $("window").scrollTop($("*:contains('" + $("input#search").val() + "'):eq(0)").offset().top);
    });

Comment: I added this to my JQuery but it's not working out:
function searchscroll() {
$("input#search").change(function(){ $("window").scrollTop($("*:contains('" + $("input#search").val() + "'):eq(0)").offset().top); });

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(searchscroll);
});

Comment: Try $(document) instead of jQuery(document) and and searchscroll() instead of jQuwry(searchscroll)

Comment: Sorry my bad, you have to change `$("window").scrollTop($("*:contains('" + $("input#search").val() + "'):eq(0)").offset().top); });` to `$("window").scrollTop($("*:contains('" + $("input#search").val() + "'):eq(0):last").offset().top); });`

Comment: This worked for me. You can check out [here](http://imspiration.net/so/searchText.htm).