# Search option in webpage for word(s), and have button to skip thru results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to use this code (**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rpY/1/)**) to have a search option in a webpage. **But I would like to have a button next to the input field that lets the user skip thru the results**. Can anyone help please?

```
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
         var page = $('#all_text');
         var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
         var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
         var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
         var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
         page.html(newHtml);
    });
```

Comment: @mplungjan, this is not a duplicate, because I want to add a button that lets the user skip thru the results in page.

Comment: Then this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487959/search-and-scroll-to-word-on-page

Comment: Seems like a complex story, that I can't figure out. Was hoping for an easier solution. Sincerely, not being lazy.